# SQL: Randomly assign value of table to another table

Tags: sql, join, random

I have two tables, A and B

A is pretty large, with about 200,00 rows, columns X1 X2 and X3. Column X1 has 50 unique values, repeated.

B is a smaller table, with 50 rows (same as unique values of X1), with columns X1, X4, X5

What I am looking to accomplish is to, join A and B so that, of the unique values of A.X1 and B.X1, B.X4 randomly goes B.X5 times to A.X6.

Comment: Why? This seems very strange to me and it goes against the concept, the nature of "relational data". Your use of words like "random" are also very confusing because it sounds like you actually want a precise "number of times" from one cell to another. Can you give us some example input and output, so myself and others can understand what it is exactly that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: My intention is to - do a what if analysis.

Comment: My intention is to - do a what if analysis.

I am trying to do grow sum of rows in A (X2+X3+X6) for each group in A. Now I know total of each group to grow by, and I know I need to update X5 number of records in A, so my total for each group in A can be grown by X4*X6. Since there are more X1s in A than in B, I wanted to randomly select X5 records in A for A.X1 and assign values of X4 to each.

Comment: This sounds like something much, much more easily done in software once the data is in memory than to do on SQL Server. Your problem isn't really amenable to the relational algebra, because of the number of "what if this" sort of ideas and the "if this then thats" in your reply. It just isn't amenable to SQL, and you'll have an easier time doing this in other languages.